# How to Install gifsicle, jpegtran, and optipng in AWS Ec2

Tags: image, jpegtran, gifsicle

I am Using a Extension to Optimize Images for Magento . Extension Need to Install gifsicle, jpegtran, and optipng to my Server But i don't know how i will Install & get exact path where installed . Anyone help me to Do this

Answer (score 12):

If it's Ubuntu or Debian, this should work

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libjpeg-progs
apt-get install gifsicle
apt-get install optipng
```

Comment: `jpegtran` can be provided also by `libjpeg-turbo-progs`

Comment: For parametrization of these commands there's an example here: https://cloudinary.com/blog/image_optimization_expert_roundup

Answer (score 0):

I installed jpegtran on CentOS 7.
I find below links are related to your problem. Are you looking for something like that ?

[application's path from command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28555/how-to-find-applications-path-from-command-line)

[How To Install JPEGtran](https://www.webmaster.net/tutorials/centos/how-losslessly-compress-and-convert-jpgs-progressive-jpgs-using-jpegtran.html)